# adding the Sum of numbers in NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, sum

I am trying to add up the sum or total of all my numbers in my `NSArray` .

I can do this perfectly okay but I have an issue. it takes out the decimal points of the numbers in my array.

The actual price of the object is R59.95 and when I `NSlog` the output is takes away .95 and only keeps the 59?

```
NSInteger sumq = 0;
for (NSNumber *num in [self.viewOrderSummaryArray valueForKey:@"price"] )
{
    sumq += [num intValue];
    NSLog(@"efeferwerwerwerwerwerw %ld", (long)sumq);
}
```

```
2014-09-19 11:05:25.016 FoodApp[25254:19075256] Output of Sum of numbers 59
```

Comment: You are using intValue, that's why it is returning integer..

Comment: There is the fact that you're using a `NSInteger`, but note that you could also use `@sum` instead of the `for loop` (less lines of code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
float sumq = 0;
NSArray *array = [self.viewOrderSummaryArray valueForKey:@"price"];
for (NSNumber *num in array)
{
    sumq += [num floatValue];
    NSLog(@"efeferwerwerwerwerwerw %f",sumq);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float sumq = 0;
```

Try printing using `NSLog(@"efeferwerwerwerwerwerw %lf", (float)sumq);`

Answer (score 0):

You are converting decimal value into integer that's why the number after digit is eliminated. so instead of this line

`sumq += [num intValue];`

write

`sumq += [num floatValue];`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code.

```
float sumq = 0;

for (NSNumber *num in [self.viewOrderSummaryArray valueForKey:@"price"] )

{

sumq += [num floatValue];

NSLog(@"efeferwerwerwerwerwerw %f", sumq);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float sumq = 0;
NSArray *array = [self.viewOrderSummaryArray valueForKey:@"price"];
for (NSNumber *num in array)
{
    sumq += [num doubleValue];
    NSLog(@"efeferwerwerwerwerwerw %.2f",sumq);
}
```